# for loop in prompt with git command : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax-error, unexpected-token

im quit new to bash and im trying to do a for loop to find all tags not converted to svn in my git directory.

I've run the following command :

```
echo < for t in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/tags); do git tag ${t/tags\//} $t && git branch -D -r $t done
```

However, i've got this error :

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

i tryed several things like moving the semicolon but its always the same error but with differents characters like &&, done or i have the following error :

```
-bash: for: No such file or directory
```

because those are unix commands, i work on cygwin on windows.

**Any ideas** ?

ps:
Im following this tuto : https://www.gitkraken.com/blog/migrating-git-svn !
thank you for your help :)

Comment: The loop, and the syntax here, are purely bash items. The only way Git comes into the picture is through the output of `git for-each-ref` and that you're running Git commands in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is input redirection. To it's right, a file name is expected (or a process specification, which then must be enclosed in parenthesis). In your case, you write the word `for` to the right of `<` and with it ask bash to use a file named `for` to replace stdin.

Furthermore, input redirection does not make sense with `echo` anyway, because `echo` does not process stdin. You are permitted to write a

```
echo <abc
```

if you want, but bash will only check the existence of the file `abc` and set up the redirection, and `echo` will silently ignore it, so there is no purpose in doing this.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) does that mean that if i run my command without echo it will run ? because i dont have any return
Edit : I ran it and it dont return any errors but i think its because for a reason i have nothing in refs/remotes/tags

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, so I can anwer this. You just posted some code and wanted to know why it does not work. If you now try something different, plesase ask a **new** question. Post your code, the result you want to have, and the result you actually get instead. And, pleas, accept one of the answers you got for **this** question, unless you feel that they don't answer what you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing a `;` before `done`.

Second, you cannot do `echo < for t in...`, if you want it to run, remove `echo <` .

You will get ambiguous redirects if you don't.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) will i still get my errors if i remove `echo` ?

Comment: @ErwanLeflot : Why do you ask an oracle, if you can simply try it out?

Comment: Yup, it, with that kind of question, is where I tend to give up. Why is the `echo <` even there in the first place?